# Browse button functionality implementation in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have to implement the browse button functionality, like when i clicked on that Browse button it has to show all types of docs & files that are in my iphone to upload to a server. Can any one help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Applications on iOS execute inside their own [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html). Therefore you can't "Browse" all the files on the device. The most you can do is give such type of functionality for the files inside your app's sandbox. However that too is not recommended.